# WebSocket client implementations for Delphi

Tags: delphi, websocket, client, components

Are there free WebSocket client implementations for Delphi? I found only this one:

[WebSockets Delphi Components](http://websockets.esegece.com/)

but it is not free.

Answer (score 1):

I've added support for WebSockets to [xxm](http://yoy.be/xxm/). Not all handlers support the required IXxmRawSocket interface, but the Apache httpd module (xxmAHttpd) and the SCGI handler do, and I still get the best results with the standalone 'raw' handler xxmHttp. See more [here](https://github.com/stijnsanders/xxm/tree/master/Delphi/demo2/13%20WebSockets).