# How to trigger an event from a web server to client en Delphi?

Tags: delphi, tcp, messaging

From a Web Server running in Windows 2012, I would need to send messages to specific clients. These clients are Delphi applications, over 2000. Each message is for a specific client, no broadcast.
Which technology can I use? I am totally new on this issue.
I am seeing Websockets, SignalR (that is based in Websockets), MSMQ, RabbitMQ, ...

MSMQ: Seems a good solution. Cons: It only works in Windows. Maybe in a future, I need to add other platforms as clients.

RabbitMQ: It is also good,but I think that it provides too features for my scenario. Basically I only need to send messages from server to specific clients.

SignalR: I am confused. It seems basically for web browsers, not for client applications. It seems a simple solution.

Basically, I am looking a simple and basic solution that I can implement in Delphi to receive messages from a web server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[WebSocket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) (a HTTP upgrade) is a light-weight option and also available for Delphi clients:

> WebSocket is designed to be implemented in web browsers and web
>   servers, but it can be used by any client or server application. The
>   WebSocket Protocol is an independent TCP-based protocol.

See [WebSocket client implementations for Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25181302/websocket-client-implementations-for-delphi)

[RabbitMQ](http://rabbitmq.com) and other solutions are useful for example if the client could be offline while the server wants to send the message. The message broker provides a store where the message will be waiting for the client, even if the server restarts. Also a message broker will reduce load on the HTTP server.